# How to get input from toggle switch JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle

I have this toggle switch in my JavaScript code:

```
var questionRequired = document.createElement("div");
  questionRequired.className = "mt-1 mb-1";
  questionRequired.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    `<label class="custom-control ios-switch">
       <input type="checkbox" class="ios-switch-control-input" />
       <span class="ios-switch-control-indicator"></span>
       <span class="ios-switch-control-description">Required</span>
     </label>`
  );
```

It is showing nicely and is being turned on and off as we can see here.

[image: Toggle switch]

My problem is that it's not doing nothing. I want to to set a variable as true if it's turned on and to false when it's turned off.

Let's say I have `var isRequired` and I wan to set it through this toggle switch. I want to do something like:

```
if (questionRequired.isTurnedOn)
    isRequired = true;
else isRequired = false;
```

Does anyone kow how I can do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified example.

Create an `eventListener` on your `checkbox`, as well as `bool` variable.

`isChecked = isChecked ? false : true;` basically means that if the value is `false`, set it to `true`, and the otherway around.

```js
var chxBox = document.querySelector(".ios-switch-control-input");
var isChecked = false; //false because the checkbox is unchecked on page load
chxBox.addEventListener("change", function(){
isChecked = isChecked ? false : true;
console.log(isChecked)
})
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" class="ios-switch-control-input" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var checked = false
var questionRequired = document.createElement("div");
questionRequired.className = "mt-1 mb-1";
questionRequired.insertAdjacentHTML(
"beforeend",
`<label class="custom-control ios-switch">
   <input onChange="isChecked()" type="checkbox" class="ios-switch-control-input" />
   <span class="ios-switch-control-indicator">. 
   </span>
   <span class="ios-switch-control-description">Required</span>
 </label>`)

function isChecked(){
 checked = checked?false:true
 return checked
}
console.log(checked)
```